# asynchronous dns lookup, but results go to the same file

Tags: python, performance, lookup, python-asyncio

I have to do a large number of DNS NAPTR lookups (think thousands per minute).
I run a Python script using dnspython, read a file and write back to another file. Request rate is ~ 300 requests/sec.
I tried to use asynchronous DNS with Python [aiodns](https://github.com/saghul/aiodns), but numbers are the same.
It is possible that my script is flawed. Please see below. This is Python 3.4.

But if results have to go back to one file, is it even possible to do lookups asynchronously?

```
import asyncio
import aiodns

...

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
resolver = aiodns.DNSResolver(loop=loop)
resolver.nameservers = ['x.y.w.z']

...

@asyncio.coroutine
def getsip(number):

    try:
        strQuery = str(dns.e164.from_e164("+" + number))
        answer = yield from resolver.query(strQuery, 'NAPTR')

        for rdata in answer:
            return rdata.regex

    except:
        return ""

with open(filename, 'r') as fread, open(filenameOut, 'w') as fwrite:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fread, delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    reader.fieldnames = fieldnamesIn

    writer = csv.DictWriter(fwrite, fieldnames = fieldnamesOut, delimiter='|')

    for row in reader:
        sys.stdout.write("Processing record number: %d \r" % (total) )
        sys.stdout.flush()
        total+=1
        answer = loop.run_until_complete(getsip(row['NUM']))
        if answer == "":
            missingAnswers+=1

        writer.writerow({'NUM': row['NUM'], 'SIP': answer})

print("Records not found: " + str(missingAnswers) + " of total " +  str(total) + " records.")
```

Comment: `loop.run_until_complete` is blocking, so you only process one request at a time. You should use something like [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather).

Comment: thanks, you put me on track and @user4815162342 answer nailed it.

Comment: BTW I recommend upgrading to at least Python 3.6. The async def/await syntax is really nice, and asyncio has matured as well - for example, `get_event_loop` does the right thing in coroutines, so you don't have to pass `loop` everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if results have to go back to one file, is it even possible to do lookups asynchronously?

If you don't care about the order of the results, it's straightforward to implement asynchronous lookups. For example, you can use [`asyncio.as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed) to schedule all coroutines to run in parallel and get notified as each completes:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def process():
    with open(filename, 'r') as fread:
        reader = csv.DictReader(fread, delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        reader.fieldnames = fieldnamesIn
        rows = list(reader)

    with open(filenameOut, 'w') as fwrite:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(fwrite, fieldnames=fieldnamesOut, delimiter='|')
        missingAnswers = 0

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        tasks = [loop.create_task(getsip(row['NUM'])) for row in rows]
        for done_coro in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
            answer = yield from done_coro
            if answer == ""
                missingAnswers += 1
            writer.writerow({'NUM': row['NUM'], 'SIP': answer})

    print("Records not found: %d of total %d records"
          % (missingAnswers, len(rows)))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(process())
```